# qemu risc-v interrupt not handled : time_lo write not implemented , time_hi write not implemented

Tags: operating-system, emulation, interrupt, qemu, boot

Recently, as I simulated a RISC-V 64 processor with a single CPU and 128MB of memory, I encountered a warning, resulting in the timer interrupt no longer managed.

The warning :

```
qemu-system-riscv64: clint: time_lo write not implemented
qemu-system-riscv64: clint: time_hi write not implemented
```

I'm emulating with this comand :

```
qemu-system-riscv64 -device VGA -machine virt -nographic -cpu rv64 -smp 1 -m 128M  -serial mon:stdio  -bios none -kernel kernel.elf
```

And compiling with :

```
riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc build/*.o boot.S  -ffreestanding -nostartfiles -nostdlib -nodefaultlibs -g -Wl,--gc-sections -mcmodel=medany -march=rv64g -Wl,--no-warn-rwx-segments -T kernel.ld -o kernel.elf
```

I tried to read about devicetree blob but I think that is not related to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That warning message was removed in upstream QEMU by implementing the correct behaviour for those writes in QEMU commit e2f01f3c2e13 in April 2022. If you use a newer version of QEMU (7.1.0 or later) you should hopefully find that these warnings go away.